# Firebase string match at end of field

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Imagin the following data:

```
{
  "name": "Abcdef",
  "age": 21
},
{
  "name": "Rodrigo",
  "age": 24
},
{
  "name": "Matt",
  "age": 30
},
{
  "name": "Def",
  "age": 21
}
```

How do I make the equivlant to this search:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = "%def"
```

so that I get this result:

```
{
  "name": "Abcdef",
  "age": 21
},
{
  "name": "Def",
  "age": 21
},
```

(or at least the first result because its %def)
I've tried `startAt` and `endAt` and also use `"\uf8ff"` but nothing seems to work....

This SHOULD be the solution:

```
ref.orderByChild("name").endAt("def"+"\uf8ff").once('value'....
```

meaning: it ends with 'def' but this doesn't work....

(I'm using the Javascript SDK)

(Note: my problem is not the capital D, its the string match)

Answer (score 2):

The method you're calling is called `endAt()`, but you are trying to use it as an `endsWith()`. That is a different type of operation, and is not supported by Firebase.

Firebase Database queries can only do prefix matching: find strings that start with a certain substring. There is no operation for postfix matching, nor for finding strings that contain a certain value.

If your use-case is really a postfix match, the common workaround would be to add a property that contains the reverse string and do a `startAt().endAt()` on that.

So:

```
{
  "name": "Abcdef",
  "name_reverse": "fedcbA",
  "age": 21
},
{
  "name": "Def",
  "name_reverse": "feD",
  "age": 21
},
```

And then:

```
ref.orderByChild("name_reverse").startAt("fed").endAt("fed\uf8ff")
```

Comment: You are confirming that Firebase can't do this...
This is walking backwards...
"oh Firebase is great"... and then can't even do a regex or something else to find a string?

Comment: So stupid that we can do prefix matching but no postfix or "in the middle" ... what a shame...

Comment: The Firebase Database is focused on fast synchronization of data between clients. As a result of that, its query capabilities are relatively simple when compared to many other databases you may have used. The answer Ron linked shows one way to combine Firebase with a full-text search engine, if you have a use-case that requires that. By combining dedicated solutions in such a way you can build/compose elaborate solutions for almost any use-case.

Comment: This answer needs more love, very clear very clever work around. Thanks again @FrankvanPuffelen