# Android - How to configure Firebase Query filter correctly?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to filter matches on the basis of team Name using a Spinner. But the problem is it is only filtering with the name of team1 only not with team2.

[image]

In the above Image `MI` and `CSK` both are different teams. Here is the code I am using for filtering.

```
filter.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Sort by Teams")) {
                    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            matchInfoList.clear();
                            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                MatchInfo info = dataSnapshot.getValue(MatchInfo.class);
                                matchInfoList.add(info);
                                Log.d("TAG", "onDataChange: " + matchInfoList.size());
                                bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }
                            adapter = new ScheduleAdapter(ScheduleActivity.this, matchInfoList);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("bothTeams").startAt(filter.getSelectedItem().toString())
                            .endAt(filter.getSelectedItem().toString() + "\uf8ff");

                    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            matchInfoList.clear();
                            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                MatchInfo info = dataSnapshot.getValue(MatchInfo.class);
                                matchInfoList.add(info);
                                bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }
                            adapter = new ScheduleAdapter(ScheduleActivity.this, matchInfoList);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

**My Spinner has**

```
List<String> teams = new ArrayList<>();
teams.add("Sort by Teams");
teams.add("MI");
teams.add("CSK");
```

Now If I filter it with MI it works fine but on CSK being selected, it shows nothing.

SO, what changes should I make in code? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Realtime Database can only filter on prefix matches, so on strings that start with a certain value. There is no way to filter for strings that end with (or contain) a certain values. Since this has been asked quite a few times before, I recommend you check out some of these answers:

- [Firebase query - Find item with child that contains string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589092/firebase-query-find-item-with-child-that-contains-string)
- [How to perform sql "LIKE" operation on firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506531/how-to-perform-sql-like-operation-on-firebase/22522874#22522874)
- [Firebase string match at end of field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053198/firebase-string-match-at-end-of-field)

---

To accomplish your use-case, you will need to *either* keep two properties (`team1`, `team2`) and perform a separate query for each property, *or* keep a separate data structure that maps each team to its matches. Something like:

```
"teamMatches": {
  "MI": {
    "-MHSZ...": true
  },
  "CSK": {
    "-MHSZ...": true
  },
}
```

You can then use this structure (often called an inverted index) to find the game IDs for the team, and then load those games. This type of lookup is not nearly as slow as you may initially think, as [Firebase pipelines the requests over a single connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786).